# New to Java, and trying to solve the main part of the exercise for the OldMacdonald Had a Farm song

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am trying to code a song using polymorphism, but I am quite new to Java coding and have a really basic experience. I could use some help with the classes, but my biggest problem is that I do not know how to write the main part of the code, I'd be very grateful if someone could help me with it.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class OldMacdonald {
public interface Farm{
    public String getName();
    public String getNoise();
}

class Dog implements Farm{
    String name;
    String noise;
    
    public Dog(String name, String noise) {
        name=name;
        noise=noise;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }
}

class Cat implements Farm{
    String name;
    String noise;
    
    public Cat(String name, String noise) {
        name=name;
        noise=noise;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }
}
    
class Duck implements Farm{
    String name;
    String noise;
        
    public Duck(String name, String noise) {
        name=name;
        noise=noise;
    }
        
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
        
    public String getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

}
    
class Cow implements Farm{
    String name;
    String noise;
        
    public Cow(String name, String noise) {
        name=name;
        noise=noise;
    }
        
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
        
    public String getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

}
    
class Pig implements Farm{
    String name;
    String noise;
        
    public Pig(String name, String noise) {
        name=name;
        noise=noise;
    }
        
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
        
    public String getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

}
    
class Song{
    private Farm [] animal = new Farm[5];
        
    Song() {
        animal[0] = new Dog("dog", "woof");
        animal[1] = new Cat("cat", "meow");
        animal[2] = new Duck("duck", "quack");
        animal[3] = new Cow("cow", "moo");
        animal[4] = new Pig("pig", "oink");
    }
        
    public void lyrics() {
        int i;
            
        for(i=0; i<animal.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Old MacDonald had a farm, E I E I O,\r\n" + 
            "And on his farm he had a " + animal[i].getName() + ", E I E I O.\r\n" + 
            "With a " + animal[i].getNoise() + " " + animal[i].getNoise() + " here and a " + animal[i].getNoise() + " " + animal[i].getNoise() + " there,\r\n" + 
            "Here a " + animal[i].getNoise() + ", there a " + animal[i].getNoise() + ", evrywhere a " + animal[i].getNoise() + " " + animal[i].getNoise() + ".\r\n" + 
            "Old MacDonald had a farm, E I E I O.\r\n\r\n");
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: You mean something like `Song song = new Song(); song.lyrics();`? Or, in shorter form, `new Song().lyrics();`?

Comment: By the way, there is a lot of redundancy here: each animal has a `name` and a `noise`. If you want to use polymorphism, consider creating a base class `Animal implements Farm` and move those properties and their getters to that base class. Then pass the initial values to the constructor. For example, the Dog class would be just `class Dog extends Animal { public Dog() { super("dog", "woof"); } }`.

Comment: Another way would be not to use fields and just return literal values from getters: `class Dog implements Farm { public String getName() { return "dog"; } public String getNoise() { return "woof"; } }`.

Comment: A cleaner way of writing the loop would be `for (Farm f : animal)`, and then use `f` instead of `animal[i]`. Also, in the physical world, a Cat is not a Farm, it's an Animal. Rename your `Farm` interface to `Animal`.

Comment: But what exactly is your question? We help with specific problem descriptions (see [mcve]), not with "here is my code, now please review it, and explain all the things I got wrong, and what needs to be added to solve my assignment" (and that last part is really hard, given the fact that you didnt exactly say what the expected output of your program should be)

Comment: @GhostCat I took "my biggest problem is that I do not know how to write the main part of the code" to mean he doesn't understand how to "kick off" his code, ie the static main.

Comment: @DaFoot That is interpretation. That might or might not be what is asking for. Always remember that questions and answers are supposed to helpful for future readers, too. Thus questions should clearly address the topic, and dont leave room for interpreation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "launch" your code somehow, in a Java standalone program like this that would be done from the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

It looks like Song is your class that actually starts everything off so you need to create an instance of that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Song mySong = new Song();
}
```

The lyrics are output by the lyrics() method, so we need to call that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Song mySong = new Song();
   mySong.lyrics();
}
```

You'll want to tweak your Song() constructor method too:

```
public Song() {
```

You might want to update your constructors in animal classes too, you were assigning the parameter to itself (easily done when using same names for variables in params and private fields):

```
public Cat(String name, String noise) {
        this.name = name;
        this.noise = noise;
    }
```

Comment: When I write Song mySong = new Song();  it gives me an error No enclosing instance of type OldMacdonald is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type OldMacdonald (e.g. 
 x.new A() where x is an instance of OldMacdonald).

Comment: Are these classes in their own files?

Comment: In the bin folder, every class has its own class file

Comment: To make this work I did the following:
- each class is now in its own file
- Farm interface is in its own file
- add 'public' to the Song constructor

Then the main method shown above works

Comment: That didn't work for me, I tried adding static to every class inside the public class and adding public to the Song constructor as you said. It did print out the lyrics but instead of the animal name and the noise it makes it prints out NULL

Comment: You don't need to add static.
Printing NULL is a different issue, original question was running the program, it is now running.

We can now look at why your getting nulls.

Comment: I think your issue is you are assigning the param value to itself.
In your constructors :
        this.name = name;
        this.noise = noise;

Comment: You will later want to look into  abstract classes so the name/noise fields aren't duplicated in each animal class

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, in your `main()`method you just have to create an instance of `Song` and call `lyrics()` on it, no? That will populate the `Farm` array with the animals and call the appropriate methods when printing the lyrics.